# Selenium WebDriver Java - Trying to log out of facebook but placed with a pop up when clicking on Log out link

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, webdriver

I am doing some testing on Facebook using Selenium and Java. I am trying to log out of Facebook which i am able to by clicking on the Log Out link however i am placed with a pop up which i am unable to bypass. I have wrote the following code but i am placed with the 'cannot find element error'.

```java
public static void logout() {

WebElement listitem = driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel"));
listitem.click();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log Out")).click();

driver.findElement(By.className(" hidden_elem" )).findElement(By.linkText("Log out")).click();

}

______________________________________________________________________
```

[image: Pop up i get when i log out]

Comment: ` 'cannot find element error'` which `findElement()` method causes the errors ? would you please post the stacktrace ? and secondly what would you like to achieve ? you are already clicking the logout button as far as I understood. Or do you need something else ?

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS 3.2_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use _Facebook API_ instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reponse. I can click on the log out button however when i click on the log out link i am placed with a pop up window shown in the figure above. I wrote the line of code below "driver.findElement(By.className(" hidden_elem" )).findElement(By.linkText("Log out")).click();". I am however placed with this error 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Log Out"}' Thankyou

Comment: @Aneesa could you please post the screenshot with UI Inspector, may be I can give a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error, i was using the wrong class element. Should have been `driver.findElement(By.className("_4t2a" )).findElement(By.linkText("Log out")).click();`